# Cannot subscript a value of type 'Double' with an index of type 'Double'

Tags: swift

Have a subscript error here but I'm not sure why. This time I made sure the types matched but now I'm getting an error because they DO match.

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[Double]' with an index of type 'Double'

```
let maxPeriod:Double = 1.5  
let minPeriod:Double = 0.1 
let invalidEntry:Float = -100
let maxPeriodsToStore:Double = 20
let averageSize:Int = 20


class Detector {

    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    var camera : AVCaptureDevice?

    var upVals: [Float] = [] 
    var downVals: [Float] = [] 
    var upValIndex: Int?
    var downValIndex: Int?

    var lastVal: Float?
    var periodStart: Float?
    var periods: [Double] = []
    var periodTimes: [Double] = []

    var periodIndex: Int?
    var started: Bool?
    var freq: Float?
    var average: Float?

    var wasDown: Bool?


    func reset() {


        for var i:Double = 0; i < maxPeriodsToStore; i++ {
            periods[i] = invalidEntry // error: Cannot subscript a value of type '[Double]' with an index of type 'Double'
        }
        for var i:Int = 0; i < averageSize; i++ {
            upVals[i] = invalidEntry
            downVals[i] = invalidEntry
        }
        freq = 0.5
        periodIndex = 0
        downValIndex = 0
        upValIndex = 0
    }
```

Original Objective-C code

```
// Detector.m

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "Detector.h"
#import <vector>
#import <algorithm>

#define MAX_PERIOD 1.5
#define MIN_PERIOD 0.1
#define INVALID_ENTRY -100

@implementation Detector

@synthesize periodStart;


- (id) init
{
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {
// set everything to invalid
[self reset];
}
return self;
}

-(void) reset {
for(int i=0; i<MAX_PERIODS_TO_STORE; i++) {
    periods[i]=INVALID_ENTRY;
}
for(int i=0; i<AVERAGE_SIZE; i++) {
    upVals[i]=INVALID_ENTRY;
    downVals[i]=INVALID_ENTRY;
}   
  freq=0.5;
  periodIndex=0;
  downValIndex=0;
  upValIndex=0;
}


// Detector.h


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define MAX_PERIODS_TO_STORE 20
#define AVERAGE_SIZE 20
#define INVALID_PERIOD -1

@interface Detector : NSObject {  
float upVals[AVERAGE_SIZE];
float downVals[AVERAGE_SIZE];
int upValIndex;
int downValIndex;

float lastVal;
float periodStart;
double periods[MAX_PERIODS_TO_STORE];
double periodTimes[MAX_PERIODS_TO_STORE];

int periodIndex;
bool started;
float freq;
float average;

bool wasDown;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) float periodStart; 


-(float) addNewValue:(float) newVal atTime:(double) time; 
-(float) getAverage; 
-(void) reset; 
@end
```

Comment: I don't know Swift, but subscripting a double seems odd. Are you sure that's legal? Plus, subscripts usually take an integral type.

Comment: What can be approved and why is off-topic on SO

Comment: I don't even see where you're getting the error, can you point out the line? And what is your intent in subscripting a number?

Comment: Are you sure that the error message is not `cannot subscript a value of type '[Double]' with an index of type 'Double'` (note the square brackets) ? `periods[i]` with `i` being a `Double` makes no sense and does not compile. – And please restrict your questions to one problem, and provide a *minimal* example demonstrating the problem, not all that unrelated stuff.

Comment: If Martin is right, you'll need to cast the double to a integer, or better use a more logical index. Indexes are integral, so, as he pointed out, a non-integral indices doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: You can define arbitrary subscripting methods in Swift, but I doubt  that this is intended here, and the built-in Array type has an integer index.

Comment: @MartinR Ya, I figured you could add subscripting to custom classes like c++ or Python, but unless it's like Scala where you can "pimp" built-ins, it shouldn't be possible. I can't imagine what 2.23[1] would return. 2?

Comment: @Carcigenicate: You can add and overload methods to built-in types in Swift (even the subscripting methods).

Comment: @MartinR Well, I guess the OP could have done something odd like that then. I have my doubts though.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: No, my recent remarks are completely unrelated to this question. OP did not overload Array methods. I just wanted to tell you.

Comment: @MartinR Oh lol, thanks. Sorry, I'm muti-tasking, so I didn't notice the topic going off topic.

Comment: Code trimmed, error message fixed and original Obj-C added for reference. I haven't added the id() function to my Swift yet. I thought I initialized in Swift by setting the values of the variables. Not sure if it's all right though.

Comment: I think I have fixed my code. No errors so that's a good sign sometimes right? http://i.imgur.com/OA4Py18.png  .   Does the logic look correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to paste a mess of code into your question, you should give a very clear indication of which line is giving an error.

I did look at your code and found the problem. You should not use a for loop with a Double to index into your array. Instead change your for loop to use an Int variable, and then cast it to a Double if you need to do math with it with other doubles.

Comment: Why not? The original working Obj-C had it. I added the original Obj-C code to my question for reference. Thanks

Comment: Your objc code shows that `i`, your subscript index, is an `int`. If you used a `double` index in objc, you'd have trouble there, too.

Comment: Yes I originally had it as Int but it was giving the same error. That whole loop has been driving me crazy. I now added Detector. h as well because there are other variables and #defines you should probably see.